# How can I control the formatting when saving a matrix to a file?

Tags: matlab, matrix, file-io, format, save

I save a matrix to a file like this:

```
save(filepath, 'mtrx', '-ascii');
```

Is there a way to tell MATLAB to write `0` instead of `0.0000000e+000` values? It would be nice because it would be faster and easier to see which values differ from zero.

Comment: If you're dealing with huge files, a binary `save` will be an order of magnitude faster. For formatted ASCII output use a uniform figure format. Mixed figure formats suffer from a huge performance penalty.

Comment: Performance doesn't matter for me in this case since it's only infrequently used and only for debugging purposes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using [DLMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html) instead of [SAVE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) since you're dealing with ASCII files. It will give you more control over the formatting. For example, you could create an output file delimited by spaces with a field width of 10 and 6 digits after the decimal point (see more about format specifiers [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html)):

```
dlmwrite(filepath,mtrx,'delimiter',' ','precision','%10.6g');
```